# UDP Sockets need help on reply.getData

Tags: java, sockets

Hey community i need some help in my java code.

I get an object in the reply.getData and I want to cast the content as a string but it does not work as I want. Thank you friends

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtdD2.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 0):

This is the output i get. If you want i can give you more information about my code.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAsop.png)